# setup:upgrade try to remove my theme!

Tags: magento2, theme, configuration, magento2.4, setup-upgrade

Like in the title, every time when I use setup: upgrade i asked to remove themes:

```
Processing configurations data from configuration file...
The following themes will be registered: adminhtml/Magento/blank, adminhtml/Magento/luma, adminhtml/MY2/THEME2
The following themes will be removed: frontend/Magento/blank, frontend/Magento/luma, frontend/THEME1/framework, frontend/MY1/THEME1, frontend/MY2/THEME2
Do you want to continue [yes/no]?
```

FRONT exception:

```
The configuration file has changed. Run the "app:config:import" or the "setup:upgrade" command to synchronize the configuration.
```

This theme was used before and works correctly where I can declare my themes for configuration?

I can't go to ADMIN if the theme wasn't removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your MY2/THEME2 I has been declared in adminhtml.
Please share the directory structure and the **Registration.php** and **Theme.xml** content files.

---

Try this

https://stackoverflow.com/q/54427330

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1**

**Please Change code in Registration.php** My2 to MY2. Your folder name is in capital and you wrote in small.

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/MY2/theme',
    __DIR__
);
```

then run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

**Way 2**

Either you can change folder name as **My2** too

then run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score -1):

theme.xml:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>My2 Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.png</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

Registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/My2/theme',
    __DIR__
);
```

[image]